# Replace the product price ($0.00) with text (for free) if it match a certain price

Tags: price

I want to replace the price (incl. label if there is any) with a text if it matches a certain price. For example:

Replace `Price: $0.00` with `for free`

This supposed to happen global - on product view, category page, cart, checkout etc. It shouldn't show $0.00 anywhere but the text only. But I'm not sure whats the 'best' approach to achieve this.

A javascript which replaces/appends the elements based on the price value?

Or should I insert a little logic in each required template?

How would you do it? I appreciate any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: you need to put login in each required tempalate.

Comment: Thanks for your estimation, Dhiren. Anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Edit CAREFULLY the catalog/product/price.phtml with an if statement.

Price.phtml is called globally to print the price, special price and discount.

**edit**

Hint: jump to the end of file where all the magic happens. Do test echos to find the correct line.